# Git: compare differences across two repositories

Tags: git

We have a template repo that we clone to create our site repos. When we upgrade sites, we just pull in the template repo into our site repo.

I'm trying to compare what's changed in the site repo at the commit that the last template repo was merged in. There may have been new commits made to the template repo that haven't been merged in yet so I don't want to include those in the comparison.

I can compare differences between the two repos using

```
git diff template/master master
```

But this compares against the most recent commit in the template repo. Is there a way to compare it at a certain commit?

Something like

```
git diff template/master@e9d5dd968 master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [`git-diff(1)` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), the syntax you're using here is:

```
   git diff [<options>] [--merge-base] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.
```

In this case `<commit>` means "anything that refers to a commit", which includes:

- branch names
- tag names
- commit ids
- relative references (like `HEAD^`)
- etc.

In other words, you can run `git diff <commit id> <branch name>`. So if `e9d5dd968` is a commit id, which seems likely, just run `git diff e9d5dd968 master`.

Comment: That seems to work. I guess I assumed that since that commit is merged in, it would compare the repository against itself instead of against the template repo.

Comment: @DavidMaksimov: once you've imported another repository's commits into your repository, *your repository has all the commits*. They are now all local commits. They are not *merged in* any more than any other fetched commits are merged in, but they *in your repository* and hence now you can address them by hash ID. This is (part of) why Git commits have unique hash IDs.

Comment: This is one of the many reasons that I say that Git is about *commits*. It's not a question of branches, or files, or whatever. *Every commit has a unique hash ID* and once it's in your repository, you can use the hash ID to find it. Branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and other names are good for two things: (a) they help you find the commits, and (b) they protect commits from being stripped away by the Grim Collector, `git gc`. A `git fetch` operation gets you the commits and normally creates remote-tracking names to protect them as well.